# Change post form

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

I have simple login form in my website. In given requirements stands, that password mustn't been sent to server, but only MD5 hash. I took simple MD5 function and now, when with onClick on submit button I change hidden text from password to md5(password). This works fine, but user sees, that something with his password is happening. I would like to make it transparent and change this particular part of form dynamically with onPost (or smth like this) callback.

I can't find any tutorials how to deal with manipulating POST table/form in javascript (jquery?) so if anyone could help I would appreciate.

Comment: how does the user see if it is a hidden field?

Comment: I meant hidden = user doesn't see plain text, just hidden (type=password)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know input fields that don't have `name` don't get submitted to the server. So you could have a hidden field and in the onsubmit event of the form copy the value of the password field into the hidden field by applying the MD5 checksum:

```
<form method="post" action="/login">
    <input type="password" id="password" />
    <input type="hidden" name="password" id="hiddenpassword" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

and then:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var password = $('#password').val();
    var md5 = MD5(password);
    $('#hiddenpassword').val(md5);
    return true;
});
```

Comment: please add `#` to the `hiddenpassword` selector. Otherwise a firm +1